# iOS, OpenGL ES. Line thickness on retina screen?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, zooming, line, thickness

I use MonkSVG library to draw some svg files. My problem is lines are always of the same thickness on retina and non-retina display). And these lines are too fat if I compare with other library for android.

I tried to reduce line thickness in calculations in code, and it works. But it seems OpenGL still think that it is runned on non-retina display and it hides lines/polygons which are enough small for a screen physical size.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you actually drawing at retina resolution on a retina screen? What's your view's `contentScaleFactor`?

Comment: After writing of this question I have found some articles with `contentScaleFactor`. But with it my pictures are drawn in 25% of screen and not from left upper corner (I have changed y-mirroring in original library only).